# Can't trigger the hidden admin account because TeamViewer filters keystrokes

Tags: windows, teamviewer

I have a remote computer that is 1,249 miles away from me right now. I have set up TeamViewer and been very tight with restrictions. I made the sticky keys toggle:

```
net user <User> /active:yes
shutdown /r /t:001
```

and the opposite for the Utility manager button on the logon screen.
My issue lies here. I can't trigger the hidden admin account because TeamViewer filters keystrokes meaning I can't press Shift 5 times to trigger "StickyKeys"

I've already tried an onscreen keyboard to try to get around this. I do not have physical access to the machine either.(Unless someone wants to pay for my flight). The machine that I've taken over is under control of someone else. There are 2 admin accounts (3 counting System) One of them is inactive and I do not have the password for the other. The 4th account is a standard guest account with Parental Controls setup.

If anyone has any way to trigger Stickykeys (Cmd maybe?) (I think AutoHotkey is installed but I'm not sure) and none of the Utility toggles in Control Panel work.

Comment: A) Don't swear it's completely unnecessary, B) what is your question...? Give us an idea of what you want to happen, what you've tried and what you've observed...

Comment: As a supplement to @Attie, see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: There's a lesson to learn here: use real security instead of weird tricks.

Comment: Ok i had 5 minutes.. it was a spur of the moment thing. What i need is to trigger sticky keys in some way.. Anyway... @attie

Comment: I'm confused... why don't you just run the commands?... perhaps in a batch file?...

Comment: I Can't Execute the command i need. Im locked into a Standared user account with Strict Parental controls enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use
```

Select option `Turn on Sticky Keys`.

This is on Windows 7. Other versions may be slightly different.

[EDIT]Ah, but you can't log in to access the CP?

Comment: I cannot. That is correct. I do have access but there are also parental controls. it is also very hard to execute Batch files. or enable sticky keys from Ease of access. I need some way to Press shift 5 times, or trigger sticky keys.